# Specific fb-comments

Tags: facebook

Im trying to create a application for users to add to fan pages and applications

im using fb-comments and every times its added to a new fan page it loads the same comments from a different page..

what im asking is could someone help me and tell me how to make unique ids for each page the fb-comments has been added too

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need a *dynamic* and ***unique*** page (with the comments plugin) for every app installation.

So if your app has been installed on Facebook page `XXXXXX`, then page `https://productdomain.com/pages/XXXXXX` will be loaded with the comments plugin related to that page only.